# Magento - Can't Access Checkout with SSL

Tags: magento, ssl

I'm having a problem in my Magento store.  If I turn on SSL on the frontend I can't access the checkout.  When I try to go to the checkout I just get bounced back to the cart page.

If the customer logs in first then it works fine but guests just can't reach the checkout.

The 'My Account' section works fine with SSL.

If I turn SSL off then the checkout can be access by everyone without a problem.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Suhosin on the server:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/15445/#t55590